# jQuery with Close button

Tags: jquery

i have this code

`<input type='submit' name='sub_form' value='Save'>` and `<a href="#" class="close">Cancel</a>`

and the jQuery is

```
$('td.add_text').click(function(e) {
    $('<img src="images/ajaxLoader.gif" id="loading" style="width:auto;" />').appendTo(".quotation_computation");
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the A tag
    var ccom = $( 'input[name=com_code]' ).val();
    var ucom = $( 'input[name=user_code]' ).val();
    var in_form = $( 'input[name=in_form]' ).val();
    var ctrack = $( 'input[name=com_for_track]' ).val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"forms/tem.php",
        data: {uc: ucom, cc: ccom, ct: ctrack, in_f: in_form },
        dataType: 'html',
        target: '.quotation_computation',
        success: function(data){
            $(".quotation_computation").find('img#loading').remove();
            $(".quotation_computation").html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

and the close button jquery

```
$(".close").click(function () {
      $(".quotation_computation").hide();
});
```

and the html

```
<div class="quotation_computation">
ANOTHER JQUERY PROBLEM
</div>
```

when i click the close button it does not working.

is my close button wrong?
okie when i click the `div class="quotation_computation">` the jquery ajax was working fine and it save to my database. but when i click the `Cancel` button the jquery ajax or the form is still there.

is there something that i need to change?

Comment: do you execute your code to attach the click event in `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: what is the "target" option for $.ajax()? I cannot find it in the API doc

Comment: do you get any javascript errors when you click the close link?

Comment: @bart -- Yes i am i just did not include that

Comment: @Novocaine88 -- no i dont get any errors...

Comment: @user1538668 [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZkQZ/) Your close works fine, so probably you have javascript errors causing the script to abort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the `<a href="#">` anchor tag will have a default action, i.e. it will force a page refresh. You will have to prevent this default action, otherwise it will refresh the page and reopen the element you just hid.

```
$('.close').click(function(e) {
   $('.quotation_computation').hide();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `href="#"` doesn't refresh the page; it merely scrolls to the top of the page. But yes, you should always use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @devnull69 weird, this might be a jsbin bug... no ?

Comment: jsbin must be binding an event to the link; check http://christianvarga.com/hreftest.html

Comment: To elaborate, under normal circumstances any link prefixed with a hash should not redirect/refresh the page. `href="#anchor"` scrolls to an element with an ID of `anchor`. When the link is _just_ a hash, there's no element to scroll to, so it scrolls to the top of the document.

Comment: So if there is Open there should be Close, but when i open the jQuery Ajax the close is not working anymore and that is so sad...